# How do I unstack only some values of a data frame (pandas/python)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
           Type             cluster       level          value
0   Accomodation    0-1 € pr.increase   from_price      0.926047
1   Accomodation    0-1 € pr.increase   from_vol        -0.367787
2   Accomodation    0-1 € pr.increase   RIC_from_Vol    561655.141824
3   Accomodation    0-1 € pr.increase   RIC_from_Price  96439.028176
4   Accomodation    1-2 € pr.increase   from_price      1.687742
5   Accomodation    1-2 € pr.increase   from_vol        -0.264432
6   Accomodation    1-2 € pr.increase   RIC_from_Vol    248475.517577
7   Accomodation    1-2 € pr.increase   RIC_from_Price  68894.222423
...
```

And I would like to obtain the following:

```
           Type              cluster     level       value            RIC
0   Accomodation    0-1 € pr.increase   from_price  0.926047        96439.028176
1   Accomodation    0-1 € pr.increase   from_vol    -0.367787       561655.141824
4   Accomodation    1-2 € pr.increase   from_price  1.687742        68894.222423
5   Accomodation    1-2 € pr.increase   from_vol    -0.264432       248475.517577
...
```

that is: take out the level = RIC_from_Vol and put its value in a new column named RIC at the same line of level = from_vol.
How can I do that?

I have tried with unstack, but had only errors...

Comment: what about `RIC_from_Price`...  where does this go ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create temporary columns before pivoting

```py
grp = ['Type','cluster','level']

condition = df.level.str.startswith('from')

(df
.assign(
    header = np.where(condition, 'value', 'RIC'), 
    level = np.where(condition, df.level, df.level.str.removeprefix('RIC_'))
    )
.assign(
    level = lambda df: df.level.str.lower(), 
    uniques = lambda df: df.groupby(grp + ['header']).cumcount()
    )
.pivot(index=['uniques'] + grp, columns='header',values='value')
.rename_axis(columns=None)
.droplevel('uniques')
)

                                                     RIC     value
Type         cluster           level
Accomodation 0-1 € pr.increase from_price   96439.028176  0.926047
                               from_vol    561655.141824 -0.367787
             1-2 € pr.increase from_price   68894.222423  1.687742
                               from_vol    248475.517577 -0.264432
```